# How to change the padding/margin between radio buttons?

Tags: html, forms, css, radio-button

Can anyone please tell me how to make radio buttons appear closer to each other? (they currentl both appear far from each other)

Please check [this link](http://www.immigration1services.com/staging/assessment/family-sponsorship-assessment/),

I tried using 'padding-left' as below, but this did not fix my issue. Could anyone please tell me what actually went wrong?

I tried:

```
.gform_wrapper .left_label ul.gfield_checkbox,
.gform_wrapper .right_label ul.gfield_checkbox,
.gform_wrapper .left_label ul.gfield_radio,
.gform_wrapper .right_label ul.gfield_radio {
  margin-left: 32%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: i think you have to use tables to align wherever you want

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-content .gform_wrapper label {
  width: 200px;
}
```

This rule is being applied to your radio button labels, that's why you have such a large space between items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this this may reduce the space between radio buttons.

.ginput_container ul li label{width:120px;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the width of the labels for "male", "female", etc. I would add a class for those labels so they don't get the 200px width you have from the other rule. In theory,

```
<li class="gchoice_6_0">
   <input name="input_6" type="radio" value="Male" id="choice_6_0" tabindex="4" onclick="gf_apply_rules(3,[0]);">
   <label for="choice_6_0" class="radioLabel">Male</label>
</li>
```

Then add the following rule to your css

```
#main-content .gform_wrapper label.radioLabel {
    width:30px; //Adjust this width for the result you want. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're going to have 2 lines, in each line there's 2 radio buttons, just like that link you provided.

**First Line**

```
<div class="radioDiv">
   <input type="radio" name="group1" class="leftRadio" value="male"/>
   <input type="radio" name="group1" class="rightRadio" value="female"/>
</div>
```

**Second Line**

```
<div class="radioDiv">
   <input type="radio" name="group2" class="leftRadio" value="single"/>
   <input type="radio" name="group2" class="rightRadio" value="married"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.radioDiv
{
   width:200px;
}
.leftRadio
{
   float:left;
}
.rightRadio
{
   float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<label for="choice_6_0" style="width: 50px;">Male</label>
```

And add the width for all labels like male etc

Answer (score 0):

You have several, contradictory rules in your various CSS files.
For instance, [this](http://www.immigration1services.com/staging/wp-content/themes/celtabusiness/presentation/styles.css) says

```
.wpcf7-form label, #main-content .gform_wrapper label {
    float: left;
    width: 70px;
}
```

while [this](http://www.immigration1services.com/staging/wp-content/themes/celtabusiness/style.css) says

```
#main-content .gform_wrapper label { width: 200px; }
```

The latter happens to override the former, but only because you include the second file later.

So you can either remove the line in the second one, or change the order in which the CSS files are included.